# How to create custom formatted complex jsons with logstash?

Tags: logstash

Is it possible in log stash with use of filters to adjust resulting json to build nested documents?

I will need to build JSON like following:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "hd_used",
    "columns" : ["value", "host", "mount"],
    "points" : [
      [23.2, "serverA", "/mnt"]
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Most likely, but it depends on the input. If you can be more specific it'll be easier to answer.

Comment: Input is a standard syslog record. I would like to have each of fields of syslog record to become columns, while values to become points.

Comment: Do not have an idea yet how to make it with standard filters without using ruby filter.

Comment: Yeah, that would take a ruby filter. Logstash isn't very well-suited for this type of stream processing. The best answer could very well be that you should use a different tool.